# Improve query oracle

Tags: oracle10g

How can I modify this query to improve it?
I think that doing a join It'd be better.

```
UPDATE  t1 HIJA
SET IND_ESTADO = 'P'
WHERE IND_ESTADO = 'D'
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT COD_OPERACION
FROM t1 PADRE
WHERE PADRE.COD_SISTEMA_ORIGEN = HIJA.COD_SISTEMA_ORIGEN
AND PADRE.COD_OPERACION = HIJA.COD_OPERACION_DEPENDIENTE)
```

Best regards.

Comment: Improve from what?? Performance??!!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/) by [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi):

> Oracle's optimizer is able to see that `NOT EXISTS`, `NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` are semantically equivalent as long as the list values are declared as `NOT NULL`.
>
> It uses same execution plan for all three methods, and they yield same results in same time.
>
> In Oracle, it is safe to use any method of the three described above to select values from a table that are missing in another table.
>
> However, if the values are not guaranteed to be `NOT NULL`, `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS` should be used rather than `NOT IN`, since the latter will produce different results depending on whether or not there are `NULL` values in the subquery resultset.

So what you have is already fine. A `JOIN` would be as good, but not *better*.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a problem, there are several guidelines for re-writing a where not exists into a more efficient form:

- When given the choice between not exists and not in, most DBAs prefer to use the not exists clause.
- When SQL includes a not in clause, a subquery is generally used, while with not exists, a correlated subquery is used.
- In many case a NOT IN will produce the same execution plan as a NOT EXISTS query or a not equal query (!=).
- In some case a correlated NOT EXISTS subquery can be re-written with a standard outer join with a NOT NULL test.
- Some NOT EXISTS subqueries can be tuned using the MINUS operator.

See [Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tuning_where_not_exists_sql.htm) for more information.